# What does translating them to Big Business and Big Tech mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Cooperate with Facebook, Apple, Microsoft...?

Harris—unlike Bernstein, who is generally well-liked in D.C. and known for his jovial nature and dad jokes, and Boushey—is often viewed as the “silent architect” or the most behind-the-scenes member of Biden’s economic policy team. His role consists of taking policy recommendations and wishes and **translating them to Big Business and Big Tech**, eventually working to come to a deal that pleases all palates.

Source: https://fortune.com/2020/11/07/biden-economic-advisors-recession-unemployment-coronavirus/

Comment: Big Tech essentially points to FAANG, however it seems something else in this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Translate" is being used figuratively.

The implication is that "Big companies" have different priorities and way of communicating to politicians.  Harris's job is to take policy recommendations and explain them to "Big companies" (especially big technology companies) in such a way that they understand the policy and will accept it.